# Android intent filter match end of path

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

How would I got about matching the end of a url?

Specifically, I want to match https://github.com/user/repo/projects for one activity, and https://github.com/user/repo with another

I tried using path pattern

```
            <data
                android:host="github.com"
                android:pathPattern=".*projects"
              />
```

or

```
            <data
                android:host="github.com"
                android:pathPattern=".*/projects"
                />
```

But this doesn't match the paths.

Edit- I have also tried

```
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="github.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/projects"
                />
```

to match https://github.com/username/repo/projects

Comment: hi!
have you find any solution?

Comment: Sort of. You can't match the individual paths, instead you match all of them and have an Activity to deal with the different possibilities. See here https://github.com/tpb1908/AndroidProjectsClient/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tpb/projects/flow/Interceptor.java

Comment: If you can't work out what you want to do with the link, then you show a dialog with the Intent, but remove your app from it. I saw it implemented in Gitskarios https://github.com/gitskarios/Gitskarios/blob/e149605b42c5a8b4a5a74d675376b6d9a512c01e/app/src/main/java/com/alorma/github/Interceptor.java and modified it for my needs.